# Script for freeing storage taken by "Other" in Mac?

Tags: macos, disk-utility

Every time I have to do this, I go to ~/Library/caches, and then ~Library/Application Support etc etc. It is a tedious process.

Is there some script online that we could just run with Sudo & make sure that all the files that are safe to be deleted are deleted?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to save disk space by deleting files which will immediately fill up again, or in the case of Application Support, potentially delete needed prefs & support files? Delete things you don't need, not things you do, or consider a larger or external drive.

Comment: `~Library/Application Support` contains application configuration files for that user. They'll get replaced when you next launch the app, but of course you'll have lost any customization. I'll bet you that your actual 'data' outweighs "Other" comfortably. That's where you need to look for stuff to off-load onto another disk.

Comment: Also, if you're talking about "Other" in About This Mac > Storage, then that's just everything that Spotlight doesn't have a category for.

Answer (score 1):

Like a couple of comments said, you should not delete files in `~/Library/Application Support` merely to free up space as there are a lot of things in there that various Applications (and macOS) need and use every time they are run.

I am sure there are scripts out there that will delete caches on demand. In fact macOS has a number of the procedures built in that run daily/weekly/monthly that do just that: *clean up cache/temporary files.* So you don't need to do this as macOS does it for you.

However, in certain circumstances and for troubleshooting purposes it is sometimes desirable to tell the system to run those procedures and delete other temporary/cache files on demand.

There are a number of "cleaning" utilities out there. I use a free one called [Onyx](https://titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html). Note that there is a different version of Onyx for each major version of macOS, so if you decide to try it, download the right version of Onyx for your version of macOS.

Comment: It's still worth saying that Caches shouldn't normally need emptying and will fill up again. The very concept that Macs should be 'cleaned' regularly is arguable at best.

Comment: I ran Onyx and did all the "maintenance" tasks. Not sure what it did, but my lap top runs a LOT faster. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @benwiggy is essentially correct, emptying caches and rebuilding the various databases and indexes **shouldn't** be necessary. But it is a a simple and harmless step. 9 times out of 10 you will notice no difference, but it is a simple step that might help, so why not. If this fixed your issue I would appreciate it if you would accept that as the correct answer.